# Echo top most parent (ancestor) category of a post

Tags: wordpress

My site has the following structure

- Fruit

  - Apples
  - Oranges

I have a post called "Pits", and Pits is in both the categories Apples, and Oranges.

In my theme, I would like to echo only the top most parent category "Fruits".
I have tried countless codes but they all seem to only echo the first category parent, and not go one level higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Get Ancestors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
$post_category = get_the_category($id);
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post_category[0]->term_id, 'category');
$root = end($ancestors);
?>
```